# Async testing a TCP server with Node net - Why are my tests throwing 'Cannot log after tests are done'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

**Context**

I have spiked a TCP Echo server and am trying to write integration tests for it. I'm familiar with testing but not asynchronously.

**Desired Behaviour**

I would like my tests to spy on logs to verify that the code is being executed. Any asynchronous code should be handled properly, but this is where my understanding falls through.

**Problem**

I am getting asynchronous errors:

`Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?`
`Attempted to log "Server Ready".`
`Attempted to log "Client Connected".`

And finally a warning:

`A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.`

**Code**

```
import * as net from 'net';
export const runServer = async () => {
  console.log('Initialising...');
  const port: number = 4567;
  const server = net.createServer((socket: net.Socket) => {
    socket.write('Ready for input:\n');
    console.log('Client Connected');
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
      echo(data, socket);
      server.close();
    })
    socket.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Client Disconnected');
    });
  });
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server Ready');
  });
  server.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  function echo(data: Buffer, socket: net.Socket) {
    console.log('Input received')
    socket.write(data)
  };
  return server;
}
```

**Test**

More such tests will be added when these are working as intended.

```
import * as index from '../../src/index';
import * as process from 'child_process';
test('the server accepts a connection', async () => {
  const consoleSpy = spyOn(console, 'log');
  try {
    const server = await index.runServer();
    await consoleConnect();
    await consoleEcho();
    await consoleStop();
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
  expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Initialising...');
  expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Client Connected');
  expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})
const consoleConnect = async () => {
  process.exec("netcat localhost 4567");
}
const consoleEcho = async () => {
  process.exec("Echo!");
}
const consoleStop = async () => {
  process.exec("\^C");
}
```

My overall question is how do I manage the events in such a way that the tests are able to run without async-related errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly waiting for your child processes to finish. Calls to exec return a ChildProcess object as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess). They execute asynchronously so you need to wait for them to finish using the event emitter api.

Ex from docs

```
ls.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

To use async await you need to convert to using a promise. Something like

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ls.on('exit', (code) => {
      resolve(code);
    });
    // Handle errors or ignore them. Whatevs.
}
```

You are closing your server on the first data event. You probably don't want to do that. At least wait until the end event so you have read all the data.

```
socket.on('data', (data) => {
      echo(data, socket);
      server.close(); // Remove this line
    })
```

Comment: That's a good point, I've removed the line but I'm getting the same key errors.